# How to determine if a Fog-uploaded cloud-storage file is public?

Tags: ruby, fog

I have a Ruby method that calls:

```
FOG_DIRECTORY.files.create(
    key: cloud_filename,
    body: File.open(local_filename),
    public: public_boolean)
```

Is there a way to then do something like:

```
CLOUD_DIRECTORY.files.get(cloud_filename).public
```

to see if the file is publicly viewable or not? I'm using S3 and could always check the S3 path but then I have to deal with code to look at files at remote URLs and, more importantly, I reduce this code to being S3-dependent, rather than easily portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a separate method to check this, but you can check if `#public_url` returns `nil` or not. See the [source](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/aws/models/storage/file.rb#L165).

Comment: Yep, just figured that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, turns out I can do this:

```
CLOUD_DIRECTORY.files.get(cloud_filename).public_url.nil?
```